# Sorting vertices and update their indices

Tags: python, mesh

I've created a mesh from a path, So I need to add sequentially a vertex group for each 5 vertices, So I need to sort vertices indices at first like in the image below. Or if there is a way to do that without need to sort vertices !

[image]